# What does "commit over" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Manasarovar)

> He is believed to be cleansed of all his sins **committed over** even a hundred lifetimes.

How's this different from **committed?** I could not figure out the meaning of "committed over".

Comment: I think "over" is not a part of the verb, but a part of a phrase describing a duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'over' here is referring to the period of time, 'a hundred lifetimes'.

In most usual circumstances this would be an example of hyperbole (an exaggerated statement or claim not meant to be taken literally). Hyperbole is often used for dramatic effect.

> You can read 'committed over' as 'committed over [a given
>   period of time]' in this case 'a hundred lifetimes'.

By saying he believed he was cleansed of all his sins 'committed over' even a hundred lifetimes. The assertion is that he feels completely and utterly guilt free.

As in this case your source is a religious text, the statement is likely meant to be taken literally (for instance buddhists believe in multiple lifetimes).

Comment: Sorry can you re-make your edit, I hit the wrong the button! I've re-edited anyway, in light of your source. Not sure if this is ok now as stands!